# Lambda Function Never Invoked From IOT-Core

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mqtt, aws-iot

I have a lambda function in AWS that should be invoked whenever an mqtt payload is sent from my iot device. I have an iot rule set up that subscribes to the mqtt topic that should convert the payload from a csv to json format, but the right now the function is never being invoked.

I've checked to make sure that the mqtt topic is being published with the right payload and it definitely is. Here is 'index.js' of my lambda function.

```
var https = require('https');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    //split lines in csv
    var lines = event.split("\n");
    var result = [];
    var headers = ["Timestamp","Temperature","humidity","counts_0.3","counts_0.5","counts_1","counts_2.5","counts_5","counts_10","pm1","pm2.5","pm10","pma1","pma2.5","pma10"];
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        var obj = {};
        var currentline = lines[i].split(",");
        for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
            obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
        }
        result.push(obj);
    }

    //store json Object in postData to be published to Losant
    var postData = JSON.stringify(result); //JSON

    var options = {
        hostname: 'triggers.losant.com',
        port: 443,
        path: '/webhooks/nV2kS3GWzETodHeFin4vlLhoAwmqkFdtfdmGV7we',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData)
        }
    };

    var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
        console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
        console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
        });
        res.on('end', () => {
            callback();
        });
    });
    req.on('error', (e) => {
        console.log(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
        callback();
    });
    // write data to request body
    req.write(postData);
    req.end();
};
```

Here are some screenshots from my IOT rule.

SQL Query
[image]
MQTT Topic being published
[image]

Function Never Invoked
[image]

Comment: How are you creating the rule, lambda and permission stack? If it is via CFT could you share it?

Comment: I used aws-iot act to create a new rule subscribed to '5aa08d17ce46980006254265'. I then added the action to invoke my lambda function, so aws automatically set the permissions for me when I added the action.